# What is lighttpd's version of "mod_substitute"?

Tags: lighttpd

Recently I read that Apache 2.2 has a new mod to patch outputs on the fly.

[mod_substitute](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_substitute.html) provides a mechanism to perform both regular expression and fixed string substitutions on response bodies.

The feature is useful when I setup testing/development environment. I can replace hostname without touching the content/code.

How can I do similar configuration in lighttpd?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no such solution.

Well, that's not entirely true. You can use a Lua script with [mod_magnet](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs:ModMagnet) to build or the HTTP body output, in a manner. However, it hasn't been optimized for that sort of usage, so it's not recommended. It may do the job in a pinch, however.

If this functionality is absolutely vital and you don't want to switch to Apache to use it, would switching to nginx be an option? [It has a substitution module](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpSubsModule).